# wordpress the_date('d F y') not working in query_posts

Tags: php, wordpress, date

in my template I want to show and specific category posts in side bar (cat = 17) so I use this code :

```
<?php $cat=17; ?>
<?php $pp = query_posts("cat=$cat&showposts=3"); ?>
<?php if( $pp )
    { 
?>
        <section class="sidebar_boxes_container">
            <div class="sidebar_headers" > اطلاعیه ها &nbsp<img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url'); ?>/img/notification.png"></div> 
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="notification_item" >
                    <span class='thumbnail' > <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('small_thumbnail');} ?> </span>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <h5><?php the_title(); ?> </h5></a>     
                        <div  style='width:100%'>
                            <div class='noti_divs' >
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url'); ?>/img/calender.png"><?php the_date('d F y') ;?>
                            </div>
                            <div class='noti_divs' id="noti_divs_author">
                                <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url'); ?>/img/author.png"> 
                                <?php the_author_posts_link();?>
                            </div>
                        </div>                                    
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </section>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php
    }  
else
    {
        echo "empty";
    } ?>
```

all wordpress functions work well but the : `<?php the_date('d F y') ;?>` returns null for all  ; while if I change the post category to another one , `<?php the_date('d F y') ;?>`  returns true date in posts
what should I do  ?

Comment: first check this `<?php the_date(); ?>`, is it showing anything

Comment: It's showing fine for me when I run your code. Are you sure these posts have been published as this will echo the *published date*?

Comment: I think that if you have multiple posts, `the_date()` only displays the date of the first instance. What happens if you try to use `get_the_date()` instead?

Comment: maybe its space between `)` and `;` , check this `<?php the_date('d F y'); ?>`

Comment: this worked : `<?php the_time('j F Y'); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add this code `<?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>` instead of this `<?php the_date('d F y') ;?>`

it will also show same result as per the date wise.

Thankx